# How to convert string '2020/07/28-19:39:45' to format like Tue Jul 28 2020 19:39:45 GMT(default javaScript format) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting string output of a function like this.`2020/07/28-19:39:45`;
then I am passing this in `moment("2020/07/28-19:39:45")` to be used in `DateRangePicker` of react. For which I am getting error invalid date in my `DateRangePicker`. So, I am trying to convert it to format of GMT, because with javaScript format `moment()` is not causing error.

PS: I am using firefox.

Comment: See the working solution below as exactly you wanted with JS.

Comment: can you try passing only the dates by removing the time component? something like s = '2020/07/28-19:39:45'; s.split('-')[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment.js warning: Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

you should replace - with empty space and then try moment();

```
moment("2020/07/28-19:39:45".replace('-', ' '))
```

Comment: Can moment.format be used to get the desired format instead of replace() ? @Raghav Bhardwaj

Comment: moment is giving Deprecation warning. and it use Javascript Date function and passing invalid date (format) to Date() will return current date only. So no , moment.format can not be used to get the desired format instead of replace()

Answer (score -2):

Probably some like this will help you start with this matter.

```html
<html>
<body>
<h4>Date to Convert: <i>2020/07/28-19:39:45</i> </h4> 
<button onclick="switchGMT()">Convert to GMT</button>

<p id="myDate"></p>

<script>
const switchGMT =()=> {
  let myDate = new Date('2020/07/28-19:39:45');
  let convertedDate = myDate.toUTCString();
  document.getElementById("myDate").innerHTML = convertedDate;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AlwaysHelping  What is the expected result?